# I am unable to open a shapefile or .GPX created in ArcMap in maptoaster as I get a "Cannot have a empty Place ID" error. How do I provide this data?

Tags: shapefile, gpx

ArcMap 10.5.1.

I have generated 320 random points inside a polygon and now want to open my point shapefile in maptoaster (A New Zealand specific mapping suite) as this is how I want to move the points onto my GPS unit.

I have tried downloading and installing the "Features to GPX" tool however I get the same error message of "Cannot have empty Place ID" or alternatively "cannot have empty field Name". I tried adding an attribute column to my points under the headings: ID, PlaceID, Place_ID, Name etc. thinking it might just need an appropriately named field. Similarly I tried a shapefile to gpx online converter and when using the resulting file I had the same error. How do I add a name/PlaceID field that will be recognized? or is there a different solution I am missing?

Comment: This sounds like a maptoaster specific issue.  You should provide some links to (or content from) maptoaster documentation on how to import/open a Shapefile.  But I suspect that this is really a question for maptoaster support.

Comment: I don't think you're claiming that ArcMap 10.5.1 is making invalid shapefiles, so I've changed the `arcmap` tag to `shapefile`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the proposed waypoint.id names below didn't seem to communicate very well but "name" without any other symbology or text worked. Below is the list from the field_hints.dat file associated with the programme.

```
waypoint.id=|ID|name|id|ident|ref|reference|key|placeid|line_label|gpspt|caption|_COL1|.
```

The maptoaster programme opened the shapefile right away and I converted to .gpx from there.